# can call back based simple action client subscribe to other topics?

Tags: ros, action, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible for a call back based simple action client to subscribe to other topics?

I want the client to subscribe to /topicA that publishes sensor_msg::JointState and pass the name, velocity, position, effort to the server.

I tried the following: (partial code): no compilation error but I'm getting segmentation fault immediately when I run the client

```
//client side code

sensor_msgs::JointState j_msg;   // global variable
 
void subCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg){

    ROS_INFO("joint_name: %f",msg->position);

    j_msg.name.push_back(msg->name[0]);
    j_msg.position.push_back(msg->position[0]);
    j_msg.velocity.push_back(msg->velocity[0]);
    j_msg.effort.push_back(msg->effort[0]);

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    ros::init(argc, argv, "action_client_node");

    std::string topicName = "topicA";
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe(topicName,1000, subCallback);

    std::string joint_name = j_msg.name[0];
    float position = j_msg.position[0];
    float velocity = j_msg.velocity[0];
    float effort = j_msg.effort[0];

    std::cout<<"joint_name: "<<joint_name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"position: "<<position<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"velocity: "<<velocity<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"effort: "<<effort<<std::endl;

    //============================================================================================
    actionlib::SimpleActionClient<my_action::MyAction> ac_("my_action_server");
    .....
    goal.target.name.push_back(joint_name);
    goal.target.position.push_back(position);
    goal.target.velocity.push_back(velocity);
    goal.target.effort.push_back(effort);
    
    .....
    
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278795/can-call-back-based-simple-action-client-subscribe-to-other-topics?/) by [avcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/32795/avcx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're getting a segmentation fault because you're trying to access the first element of the name vector of the j_msg object. Because the callback function you've registered to 'topicA' has not been called yet the vectors within the j_msg object are all empty so trying to access the first element will segmentation fault.

If you create a global variable which is a pointer to the SimpleActionClient object and set it when you create this in main then you should be able to update this within the callback function without any problems.

It's also worth noting that the 'topicA' callback adds extra elements into the name, position, velocity and effort vectors each time it's called, but you're only ever reading out the first element. This might not result in the behaviour you expect.

Let us know if you get this working.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avcx](https://answers.ros.org/users/32795/avcx/) on 2018-01-05**:
I did exactly the same and it worked like a charm. Thanks for a great answer. Here is what I did: briefly

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<my_action::MyAction> Client; //global
Client *clientPointer; //global
..
inside main
Client ac_(serverName);
clientPointer = &ac_;
ac_.waitForServer();
..

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-05**:
Great stuff, glad it's working for you now.

**Comment by [frizh](https://answers.ros.org/users/54903/frizh/) on 2020-11-10**:
Hii
i'm also geting this error but i don't understand the solving
can you explain to me how to fix that code?
thanks